# How to set cookie from html form to php

Tags: php, html, cookies

I want to read cookies when page loads and I want to be able to save them when user presses the submit button on the form.

As the server side script is runing before the html loads I don't know how to send user info from the form into the `setcookie()`

For example:

```
    <form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="login-exec.php">
          <div><input name="login" type="text" class="textfield" id="login" /></div>
          <div><input name="password" type="password" class="textfield" id="password" /></div>
          <div><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="true" id="checkbox" /> Remember me</td></div>
    </form>
```

this is then function that is made to set cookies:

```
setcookie(name, value, expire, path, domain);
```

How to put my info from the form into the `$value` variable when checkbox is checked?
Do I need to check checkbox value in html or php?

Comment: You could set the cookie in login-exec.php

Comment: Don't save passwords in cookies

Comment: I was thinking to save username and password so user doesn't need to login everytime

Comment: Is there any better way to do it? Encryption?

Comment: Thank you for the down vote, you don't like question so you down voted. Maybe this is something simple for you but this is pretty new to me, so have respect. This is not going for anyone particular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must do that in **login-exec.php** using the **$_POST** variable which will contain your form's data:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
    // guessing how to retrieve the other fields is left as an exercise
    // setcookie('name', 'value');
}
?>
```

But, as others have said, you should really read some articles about how to make a safe remember-me system (or ask on SO!).